# Keynote: change Shape Styles via AppleScript or JXA

Tags: applescript, keynote, javascript-automation

This is for either AppleScript or JXA:

I'd like to automate a task in Keynote, which involves Keynote's Shape Styles: if any existing shape has a certain RGB-value, I'd like to assign a specific Shape Style to it.
So first question would be: is there a Shape Style class? And can RGB values be read out? (I've seen a similar script for Powerpoint in Visualbasic).

Answer (score 0):

No such class. These are the properties of a shape, which are the styles of the shape, some of which you can alter, some of which are read-only:

> {class:shape, opacity:100, parent:slide 1 of document id
>   "54ACE2F5-F2CF-41B8-B5B0-0FDC27778D96", reflection showing:false,
>   background fill type:advanced image fill, position:{609, 157}, object
>   text:"", width:100, rotation:0, reflection value:0, height:100,
>   locked:false}

Which is to say: `shape`, `opacity`, `parent`, `reflection showing`, `background fill type`, `position`, `object text`, `width`, `rotation`, `reflection value`, `height` and `locked`.

A basic operation in AppleScript to find this type of information is to do (for example):

```
tell application "Keynote"
    properties of shape 1 of slide 1 of document 1
end tell
```

But, as you can see, the only thing close to fill color is `background fill type`, which is read-only. You can assign a text item to the shape and get/set it's text color, but that's it, it seems. It's a woeful limitation.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Much appreciated!!